# What is target directory in maven-archetype-webapp in Eclipse and shall I add it to .gitignore?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, jakarta-ee, gitignore

This is my sample Maven Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse (maven-archetype-webapp).

Which folders shall be excluded from git (that is added to .gitignore)?

I used to think that target folder in Maven means compiled .class files and is never needed to be committed/pushed - so I thought of adding entire `target/` to *.gitignore* - because I don't want maven-fetched jars in git repo. But the problem is that then it would ignore my index.jsp (and other jsp/html files to be added) and web.xml !!!

Besides target folder contains MyListener.java, not MyListener.class!

And target folder does not contain Student.java or Student.class (this class is used inside MyListener.java with Spring ClassPathXmlApplicationContext as `Student student = (Student) context.getBean("student");`)

[image]
[image]

P.S. The contents of `Deployed Resources` folder is this:
[image]

[Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

> There are just two subdirectories of this structure: src and target.
>
> The **target directory is used to house all output of the build.**

P.S. **I added target to .gitignore and the project was safely cloned and built on another machine! So - solved!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs say, in the target directory are class files, jars and other output files.
They are automatically generated and would only spam commits.

Since that, you shoud add the `target` directory to your `.gitignore`

**[Tip]**

Use [gitignore.io](http://gitignore.io) for generating your `.gitignore`

Comment: I am afraid I will lose Student.class, index.jsp, web.xml and MyListener.class - they shall not only get deployed but also be saved to Git.

Comment: The `.class` files are auto-generated(if you have the `.java` files in your source folder and `index.jsp` and `web.xml` are only copied from `src/main/webapp`. Also, that may be overwritten by commands like `mvn install` and will be deleted when running `mvn clean`.